# Simple applications and drivers

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to write simple apps and drivers. Some quick tipps and tutorials about that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32386/simple-applications-and-drivers/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-04-23**:
What do you mean with simple apps and drivers? Do you have something specific in mind? The beginner tutorials are normally a good place to start.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-04-23**:
Well I mean  a simple application like to subscribe/publish to topics, use rosbag for replaying data (like some  examples of data simulated from various sensors to play with). Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [beginner tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1